# Model generator for Spring Persistance

Tags: delphi, spring4d

Does anyone knows if there is an existing model generator for the Marshmallow (spring persistence). It is not that handy to write all the classes and foreign keys etc by hand.

Thank you in advance.

```
type
  [Entity]
  [Table('Products')]
  TProduct = class
  private
    [Column('PRODID', [cpRequired, cpPrimaryKey, cpNotNull, cpDontInsert], 0, 0, 0, 'Primary Key')]
    [AutoGenerated]
    FId: Integer;
  private
    FName: string;
    FPrice: Currency;
    FQuantity: Integer;
    fCreationDate: TDate;
    fCreationDateTime: TDateTime;
    fCreationTime: TTime;
  public
    property ID: Integer read FId;
    [Column('PRODNAME', [], 50, 0, 0, 'Product name')]
    property Name: string read FName write FName;
    [Column('PRODPRICE', [], 0, 0, 0, 'Product price')]
    property Price: Currency read FPrice write FPrice;
    [Column('PRODQUANTITY')]
    property Quantity: Integer read FQuantity write FQuantity;
    [Column('PRODCREATIONDATE')]
    property CreationDate: TDate read fCreationDate write fCreationDate;
    [Column('PRODCREATIONDATETIME')]
    property CreationDateTime: TDateTime read fCreationDateTime write fCreationDateTime;
    [Column('PRODCREATIONTIME')]
    property CreationTime: TTime read fCreationTime write fCreationTime;
  end;
```

So that the generator generates the pas file for the tables in the DB.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/spring4d/issues/75/

Comment: Thank you @StefanGlienke for an information.

Comment: i don't see any reason why this question was downvoted